# Using screenmanager for changing text by a second screen

Tags: kivy

Master,

I'm using `Screenmanager` to make two screens. On my first screen I want to show a (changing) number. On my second screen I want to change this number by clicking a button. Unfortunately if I go back to my first screen, the number is still the old one. How can I update it? `NumericProperty()` doesn't seem to be enough?

**main.py**

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.7.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

class Home(Screen):
    number = NumericProperty()


class Change(Screen):
    number = NumericProperty()

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.number = 0
        root = ScreenManager()
        self.home = Home(name='home', number=self.number)
        root.add_widget(self.home)
        self.change = Change(name='change', number=self.number)
        root.add_widget(self.change)
        root.current = 'home'
        return root

    def go_to_change_screen(self):
        self.root.current = 'change'

    def changenumber(self):
        self.number = 1
        self.root.current = 'home'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**my.kv**

```
#:kivy 1.7.1

<Home>:
    Button:
        text: 'Go to Change-Screen.\n number = ' + str(app.number)
        on_release: app.go_to_change_screen()

<Change>:
    Button:
        text: 'Change'
        on_release: app.changenumber()
```

Comment: I tried with removing the home-screen (here with `self.root.remove_widget(self.home)`) and adding it again. But that changed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that your kv file assign text just once, when it builds buttons, so if you want to change this text later, you should reassign text to the button (read about ObjectProperty and kv id [here](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html)).

Comment: The official [description](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code) you linked only works if all buttons and the `changenumber` function are in the same class. (How they've written themselves: The `number` "can be used anywhere in the class"). I would like to use a second screen (a second class) to run a function in the `app` class and show on the first screen the new value (of the variable defined in the `app` class).

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the instantiations of your two original Screen classes will yield two different "number numeric properties" which are only visible locally and not at the *app* level; they are not linked in anyway.

When sharing processes across screens, I place all event-related code and shared information in the ***ScreenManager***. The event-related code can then access and manipulate all the methods and properties of  classes instantiated within the ScreenManager (this includes the Screen classes themselves). You can also easily access these methods and properties from your KV file via ***root.manager***.